# ios APNS restriction of count

Tags: ios, push, in-house-distribution

I'm making an in-house application for email service, and maybe more than 10,000 users will use this application(because this is university email service). I'm worried about that there are more than 100,000 pushes in a day. Is there any restriction of push in Apple, or something cause problem at Server side, Client side, APNS, etc in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You should be fine if you follow the [General Provider Guidelines](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/CommunicatingWIthAPS/CommunicatingWIthAPS.html) to the letter.  Most importantly:

1) Send notifications in batch.

2) Check regularly with the feedback service and do not send to devices reporting failed deliveries.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should search about feedback.